# Access to user's name and profile picture in the AppEngine's app

Tags: google-app-engine

AppEngine has Users service to access Google account information. Unfortunately, it doesn't provide access to the Google account's many properties, specifically name and profile picture. Could anyone advise a proper way of retrieving that information?

Answer (score 4):

The Users API does not provide any way to access anything other than the user's email address. Any other information has to be accessed independently, using APIs such as the [Google Profiles API](http://code.google.com/googleapps/domain/profiles/developers_guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

Google Profiles API would not work for default Google (gmail) Accounts, unfortunately.

http://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1925

If you want to get access to name and email, I believe, you could use attribute exchange (AX) with Google's OpenID. You can even combine OpenID with OAuth. I'm not sure, however, if you can get access to picture URL.