# Obtain user profile picture/badge for the signed-in google user

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, authentication, profile

My web application uses google user-id for authentication. How do I fetch the currently signed-in user's profile picture/badge in javascript?

**Note:** I only have the access to the user's email address and id. I don't have the profile id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you're using the Users API, which doesn't offer access to profile info: [Access to user's name and profile picture in the AppEngine's app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353505/access-to-users-name-and-profile-picture-in-the-appengines-app/7356001#7356001).

Depending on which kind of users your app is dealing with (any gmail user, Google Apps users, Google+ users, etc) using other APIs could be attempted instead: [Google+ API](https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/), [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/?csw=1), etc.

Another possibility would be switching to some other authentication method offering access to profile info. See [What is the difference between Google identity toolkit, Google OAauth and Google+ sign in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25442786/what-is-the-difference-between-google-identity-toolkit-google-oaauth-and-google/31053422#31053422)